# php recursiv function "return" not work?

Tags: php, recursion, return

I try to get the value `10` but it comes `NULL`. What goes here wrong? Tested on PHP 5.3

```
<?php

function foo($i=0){
  if($i<10) foo($i+1);
  else return $i;
}

$value = foo();
var_dump($value);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `i` is 10 in `foo`, the value 10 is returned to the calling instance of `foo` (where `i` was 9) and then the function ends without an return statement.

You probably want

```
function foo($i=0) {
  if($i<10)
    return foo($i+1);
  return $i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You code works like this:

```
function foo($i=0){
  if($i<10) 
    foo($i+1);
  else 
    return $i;
  return; // implicit return
}
```

Since `$i` < 10 you recur until it's 0 but the return value isn't returned or used. Outside of the `if` there is an implicit return that returns no value.

In order to return the value from the recursion you need a return statement:

```
function foo($i=0){
  if($i<10) 
    return foo($i+1);
  else 
    return $i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if($i<10) 
  return foo($i+1);
else 
  return $i;
```

because otherwise it never returns.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the value:

```
function foo($i=0){
  if($i<10) {
    return foo($i+1);
  } else {
    return $i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

function foo($i) {

```
if ($i < 10) {
    echo "a",$i;
    $i=foo(($i + 1));
}

return $i;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Your understanding echo `$i` and then test at the last function never calls the else statement try without `else`  statement.

```
function foo($i=0){
    if($i<10){
        foo($i+1);
        echo $i;
    }
    return $i;
    }

$value = foo();
var_dump($value);
```

Comment: It will in the 10th recursion or if you call it with 10. $i=0 make 0 the default value only and every recursion supplies an argument.